# How to verify dumpedfiles.sql is taken correctly with no errors

Tags: centos, mysql

I had a problem before on one of my servers, 
Database backup was taken using:
mysqldump --single-transaction

and one day i needed to restore the daily backup and found the dumpedfile.sql is corrupted for some reason which means i've no backups for the databases.

So now i'm looking for a tool  to verify that the sql file has been taken successfully with no errors and its able to restore any time.

Please advise

Comment: The only way to properly test backups is to test restoring them.  If you're writing binary logs (like used for replication), then you could build a new slave with your backup and connect it to the master for verification.

Comment: i think there must be some tools !

Comment: If there were they would be giving you a false sense of security.  Seriously, the only way you can be certain your backup is good and will restore properly is to test restoring it.  Anything else is just for show; you would be negligent in your duties as a systems professional if you relied on one.